# Disabling Submit Button in PHP for Unauthorized User Group

Tags: php, button

I'm trying to figure out how to disable the submit button if the user is not part of a specific group, but I can only find examples for after the form is submitted. Can someone help out?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="SubmitFileButton"> Submit </button>
```

Comment: check the qualifier when the HTML page is loaded and if the qualifier fails, have a string `$disabled = "disabled";` set and inserted into the submit button HTML code. However, this should also be checked upon form submission as well. Don't trust user input.

Comment: Where in the HTML code would that be inserted into?

Comment: Well, the submit button code, to disable most users from pressing the button. That's what you're looking for, isn't it?

Comment: `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="SubmitFileButton" <?php print $disabled;?> >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get grup data in this page.you can get group data in this page then after you can write php condition in this button.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="SubmitFileButton" <?php if(not part of group) disable; ?>> Submit </button>
```

Comment: I understand you're answering in a figurative sense, but shouldn't it be more like `<?php if (not part of group) echo 'disabled' ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="SubmitFileButton" disabled="disabled"> 
   Submit 
</button>
```

I assume that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Whilst this is correct, this code will disable *every* instance of the button, but the OP wants it to only disable based on some other criteria....